# What should I do with my question when I received the "tumbleweed" badge with it?

Tags: discussion

Just in case, tumbleweed badge = question without answers, comments and low on views for a whole week.

I asked a question that I think is interesting for a lot of people, but I did the mistake to post it on saturday, so it got buried soon enough and received only 18 views on a whole week.

What should I do?

By the way, the question is this:
[How to avoid (or lessen the risk of) corruption of the suo file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26314385/how-to-avoid-or-lessen-the-risk-of-corruption-of-the-suo-file)